# What am I? A word

Tags: riddle, word

I'm not part of order, nor am I a friend,

you'll be able to tell when I turn the bend.

When I come round, you'll start to worry,

and maybe even break out in a hurry.

You might feel me in your bones or in your gut,

but maybe, just maybe, I'll get you out of your rut.

Far more likely indeed I'll just make things much worse,

thankfully I probably won't make you require a hearse.

Hint:

> The word has seven letters.

Comment: Oh boy, [Tax Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tax_Day) was just this week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are

> **Anxiety**

```
I'm not part of order, nor am I a friend,
```

> Anxiety can be a mental *dis*order, and isn't a friend.

```
you'll be able to tell when I turn the bend.
```

> "Around the bend" is an idiom for having a mental disorder.

When I come round, you'll start to worry,

> Yup

and maybe even break out in a hurry.

> Anxiety can make you agitated and act rashly, or break out in a sweat.

You might feel me in your bones or in your gut,

> Yup

but maybe, just maybe, I'll get you out of your rut.

> Dealing with anxiety may be an impetus to change your situation.

Far more likely indeed I'll just make things much worse,

> Anxiety can often be debilitating to physical and psychological functioning.

thankfully I probably won't make you require a hearse.

> Anxiety on its own is not a fatal disorder.